# Is there any way to get Jython py_compile to not record the absolute path of the source file?

Tags: python, jython

I'm using [py_compile](https://www.jython.org/docs/library/py_compile.html) in Jython 2.5.3 to compile some Python files to $py.class files.

I've noticed that this module seems to record the absolute path to the source file, so that if I move the location of the source tree, the $py.class file changes.

**Is there any way to get py_compile to record relative paths rather than absolute paths?** I can see why it would need to be there for exception handling, but I don't want references to the absolute path, since it leaks information about where it is located on the computer that compiles the .py file.

---

example:

jython1.py:

```
import sys
import py_compile

if __name__ == '__main__':
    infile = sys.argv[1]
    py_compile.compile(infile)
```

jython2.py:

```
def doit(a,b):
    print a/b

doit(3,4)
doit(3,0)
```

and I can run this via

```
java -jar path/to/jython-standalone-2.5.3.jar jython1.py jython2.py
```

The resulting jython2$py.class file contains the path to jython2.py

Answer (score 2):

Oops, didn't read the [documentation](https://www.jython.org/docs/library/py_compile.html) closely enough. There's a third argument to `py_compile.compile()` (my emphasis):

> py_compile.compile(file[, cfile[, dfile[, doraise]]])
>
> Compile a source file to byte-code and write out the byte-code cache
>   file. The source code is loaded from the file name file. The byte-code
>   is written to cfile, which defaults to file + 'c' ('o' if optimization
>   is enabled in the current interpreter). **If dfile is specified, it is
>   used as the name of the source file in error messages instead of file.**
>   If doraise is true, a PyCompileError is raised when an error is
>   encountered while compiling file. If doraise is false (the default),
>   an error string is written to sys.stderr, but no exception is raised.